# Failure: GCE credentials requested outside a GCE instance

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

When I try to copy my files to Google Cloud Storage using

```
gsutil cp  file.gz gs://somebackup
```

Get this error:

```
Your "GCE" credentials are invalid. For more help, see "gsutil help creds", or re-run the gsutil config command (see "gsutil help config").
Failure: GCE credentials requested outside a GCE instance.
```

BTW, this was working until last yesterday.

Comment: Are you running on GCE?

Comment: Yes I do run this command from my GCE instance.
I also login with:
`gcloud auth login`

Comment: @RezaShahbazi did you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this as well and contacted Google support. It's occurring because the instance was created with Storage permissions as Read Only, visible on the instance details page:

[image]

Apparently this can't be changed after the instance is created (!). Our solution was to mount a temp disk, copy the file there, unmount it and then remount it on a second instance (with proper Storage permissions) and do the gsutil copy from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a "gcloud auth login" from the command line

Comment: Yes I did try this (`gcloud auth login`). Same error again.

Comment: make sure that Google Cloud Storage API is enabled in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before and my problem was that I've set the wrong project.

Make sure you set the project ID and not project name when you run
`gcloud config set project <projectID>`